# If you realize you're carrying on Shabbat, what's the best thing to do?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

I've heard that you should put it down on a makom patur while still walking. However, a true makom patur is tall and skinny, like a post, and therefore possibly difficult to find.

I've also heard that you walk into a reshus hayachid - private property - and, again, while still walking, hand it to another person who is also inside the same reshus hayachid. The rationale here is that "carrying" requires both an akira (uprooting) and hanacha (setting). In this case, then, since you're still walking it's not considered a true hanacha.

Are either of these correct? If not, what should be done?

Comment: And the worst thing to do if you see someone carrying is to yell at them (which will cause them to stop).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CYLOR

If you can find a Makom Patur (a fire hydrant), do so.

If not, then if you didn't stop in a rshus harabim, go back to a rshus hayachid (private property) so that there will be no uprooting with setting down.

The main thing to remember is DO NOT STOP if you find yourself carrying. IF you did, leave it where you are (You just did a hanacha by setting it down; don't now do an akira, uprooting it by carrying it furrther).

Comment: "then if you didn't stop in a rshus harabim..." since leaving the rshus hayachid? Or at this moment you're still walking?

"go back..." should I read into the "back" or can you go into any rshus hayachid?

Does passing it to someone else help or once you've arrived in a rshus hayachid you can just lay it down by yourself?

Comment: Once you're in a Reshuth HaYahid, you should be able to lay it down yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might depend if your in a real reshus harabim or not. If you're just in a karmelis, you may not need to worry about it as much. I think if you walked into a reshus harabim but did not stop you should turn around and go back to the reshus hayachid you came from. If that's not possible, you should try getting to another reshus hayachid to drop it off in. If you have to pause at a red light, move in circles so as to avoid stopping.