# What are the issues with wearing gloves on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

I know that there are differing opinions on wearing gloves outside on Shabbos, and whether that constitutes carrying, or may lead to carrying. So, what are the halachic problems/concerns with wearing gloves outside on Shabbos? Which Rabbonim hold what?

(Obviously, this only applies when there is no eruv, or if one doesnt hold by whatever eruv there is.)

Comment: The Shibbolei Haleket forbids it as one may take them off: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=15614&st=gloves

Comment: @ShmuelBrill sounds like an answer to me. Post it

Comment: @msh210 already mentioned everything there that is nogeah as an answer. The "chiddush" that is mentioned there is 1. According to everyone it's permissible to where gloves if they are in a group bdeieved 2. There were different customs whether or not to use gloves and 3. Bdieved one can pass books from person to person until one reaches a Rshus hayachid.

Comment: Though I don't know how much of the piskei dinim mentioned in Sefer Zichronos are accepted Lehalacha. The Frierdiker Rebbe mentioned that she "paskined" in this way and her husband and father agreed later. Was that psak accepted by other poskim of their generation?

Comment: Moreover, it's interesting that the Previous Rebbe said that they "stopped in bewilderment". Practically they should probably [not have done that](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9303/732) as they just made a "hanacha".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[*Shulchan Aruch* 301:37](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&pgnum=168) says:

> It's permissible to go out on *Shabas* with handgear called [*guantes*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guante#Spanish) [=gloves]. But some are strict to require that one sew them before *Shabas* to the handgear [=sleeves] of his clothes, or tie them to them well with a durable knot; and it is seemly to worry about that view.

[*Mishna B'rura* (ad loc.)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&pgnum=168) says:

> Those who are strict, it's because sometimes he needs to feel with his hands to remove a bug that's stinging him, and we worry that he may forget and come to carry [the removed glove] four *amos* in a *r'shus harabim*.

And on the *SA*'s "it is seemly to worry about that view", *MB* says:

> Now they are accustomed to be lenient, maybe because, according to many *pos'kim*, we have no *r'shus harabim d'oraysa*, so there's no reason to make the decree "... lest he come to carry in a *r'shus harabim*". However, it seems from the *acharonim* that although one should not admonish those who are lenient, any *baal nefesh* should be strict.

[*Aruch Hashulchan* (:105)](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%90#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A9.D7.90_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.A7.D7.94) says:

> The reason for those who permit is that it's clothing like any other; the reason for those who forbid is that it's impossible to feel with one's hands while they're in gloves, and he may wish to feel something and so remove his gloves and carry them four *amos*. Therefore we need them sewn or tied, so they are part of the garment [they're sewn or tied to]; some say tying doesn't make them subsidiary to the garment, and when they are [tied on but] not worn they are considered to be carried.... It is seemly to be strict [with gloves that are neither sewn nor tied to a garment], and that is the custom; if the cold is severe, one can permit it, obviously.

(All translations are my own.) For practical guidance, as always, consult your rabbi.

Answer (score 2):

I might conclude that wearing gloves within an eruv would be permitted to those who carry other things within the eruv.

Comment: Welcome to Judaism.SE!  Yes, I think the questioner was referring to a case where there was no eruv. But you are correct that he did not make that clear. Why don't you leave him a comment asking to clarify that point? Look forward to seeing you around.