# Are there any Halachic issues with regard to wearing earmuffs outside on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

Does wearing earmuffs outside on Shabbos (without an eruv) constitute "carrying"? Are there any other issues with it, like [wearing gloves](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12888/what-are-the-issues-with-wearing-gloves-on-shabbos/) where there is a concern that one might take them off?

Do any Rabbonim discuss this issue?
(Looking for sourced answers please.)

Answer (score 3):

I have always heard that earmuffs are different than gloves. Gloves someone may by mistake take them off in Reshus HaRabim to give Shalom to another person, however earmuffs we are not afraid that you may take them off. However a quick search on the internet does show some Poskim that equate earmuffs to gloves.

Comment: Any sources for this?